# Modal bootstrap Angular - O content da modal está dentro de um ng modal window

Tags: angular, front-end, bootstrap-4

Estou usando o bootstrap modal para angular, conforme a documentação, [este](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) é o modo de utilizar o framework. Estou seguindo exatamente como no exemplo. Eis um pouco do meu codigo:

```
<ng-template #modalcontent let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Editar equipamento</h4>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="close close-button"
      aria-label="Close"
      (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')"
    >
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <!-- FORM E OUTROS CONTEUDOS -->
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Botão que aciona o modal:

```
<a
            (click)="open(modalcontent, equipment)"
            class="waves-effect teal lighten-4 btn"
            >Editar</a
          >
```

Para abrir o modal, no meu `component.ts`:

```
open(content, equipment?) {
    this.modalService
      .open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: "modal-basic-title" })
      .result.then(
        result => {
          this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        },
        reason => {
          this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        }
      );
  }
```

E para fechar:

```
private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    this.grainData = [];
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return "by pressing ESC";
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return "by clicking on a backdrop";
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
```

Meu problema é que o modal não fica exatamente como no exemplo do bootstrap. Além de utilizar o bootstrap, estou usando o Materialize css. Eis o resultado do meu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como mostrado na foto, só consigo fechar o modal se clicar na área indicada. **Como consigo abrir o modal padrão do bootstrap?**

Penso que pode ser um problema entre o materialize e o bootstrap, porém, como visualizado, estou usando o ng-template, conforme documentação do bootstrap.

Comment: Você pode comentar o código do Materialize para ver se realmente ele esta afetando a sua modal. Caso esteja afetando, então você pode especializar seu `css`, adicionando mais classe, a sua modal. Caso não seja o Materialize, você pode procurar o que esta afetando a sua modal atraves de uma `inspeção`. Só clicar com o botão direito em cima da componente e ir em `inspecionar` . Assim você quais elementos, ou quais tag, estão modificando-a.

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade o problema era realmente o Materialize css com o Bootstrap (conflito de css). Bastou eu sobrescrever o css para resolver o problema.